# Ionic2: Login with a External Link

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am having some big problems in a method that the client asked us to authenticate the login in our app.

I need to know how to make where, as the person opens the app he/she get redirected to an external web page and proceed with the login in this page. Then, it have to return to the app with the body that contains in the page’s HTML that will be redirected after the login.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use the Ionic Auth service with the Custom method.

http://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/custom-auth.html

The docs explain this pretty clearly - you set up some code on your server to receive in the username/password submitted on the app login screen, you validate the details and then send back a JWT.

The user is then logged into the app.

You therefore don't need to redirect the user to a new page to login, this can be handled within the app itself.

Comment: Yes I had thought of this possibility, but the client does not want anything to be in JSON

Comment: Do you know their reason why? There needs to be some way to communicate between the back end system and the app and JSON is purely a method of doing this.